# Ways of finding the center of curvature

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, curvature

What are some ways of finding the center of curvature of concave and convex mirrors (spherical)?

For example, I can double the distance of focal length on the principle axis to find the center of curvature of concave mirror.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A foucault (knife edge) test is another way of finding the focal length.

Answer (score 2):

A concave mirror used for focusing light is parabolic, not spherical.  There therefore isn't a "center of curvature".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the radius of curvature is twice the focal length from the pole (A in upper diagram, P in lower diagram) : $R=2f$.

- You can obtain an approximate value of $f$ by finding the point at which a distant object is focussed, as suggested by the 2nd diagram. Or you can obtain $R$ as the distance at which an object is focussed at the same distance (inverted).
- You can get a more accurate value of $f$ by plotting a graph of image vs object distances, in the form $1/v$ against $1/u$. The intercept is $1/f$.
- You can use a special tool such as a [**spherometer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherometer) to find radius of curvature directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the object distance and image distance, you can solve for the focal length f using the mirror equation. Then you will also know the center of curvature since it is 2 times f.